# raspberry pi zero gpio not working

Tags: rpi.gpio, pi-zero

Im doing a simple blink test on my raspberry pi zero but I am having trouble getting my gpio pins to work. I have already installed wiringpi and RPi.GPIO. My setup is simple, I connect pin #1(3.3v) to power and pin #6(ground) to ground. I have tried this setup with a battery and it seems to work just fine. Also, when I run "gpio readall" I get a table with no errors. Here is the picture of my setup:

[image: blink project setup]

I have tried the same test with a 3v battery after my test with the raspberry pi. The LED does turn on.

[image: 3v battery test]

Answer (score 3):

The power and ground pins are not GPIO.

You appear to have shorted a LED between 3V3 and ground.  That will have destroyed the LED.

https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-use-a-breadboard

Comment: No the LED still works. I have tried this with a 3v battery. The LED works fine.

Comment: The only way it would still work is if you are fortunate and fitted it back to front.  It's not lit in your photo.

Comment: As i mentioned before, I have tried this with a 3v battery after I posted this question. The LED lits up. My problem is not with the LED.

Comment: ...and as I pointed out to you the only way it would still work is if you connected it back to front.  Your problem is you do not understand how to use a breadboard which is why I posted the link.